# Ubuntu 23.10 can't register my Logitech MX Keys Mini

Tags: bluetooth

After I changed from 23.04 to 23.10 my Logitech MX Keys Mini isn't visible anymore as a bluetooth device. Quite irritating, since I only used this very handy keyboard. Hope I can get some help here.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling low energy support for bluetooth, in terminal:

```
sudo btmgmt le on
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it doesn't work unless I have use special keys to reset the keyboard?